# Explanation of Hadith on Authority of Quraish

Tags: hadith, government

Narrated Ibn `Umar:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Authority of ruling will remain with Quraish, even if only two of them remained."

[Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/11)

Can you explain why the ruling should be from Quraish? What is the scope of the ruling?
If a government is not from Quraish, then will it not be considered as an islamic government? (we had non Quraish like Ottoman)

Comment: The connotation to the above saying was to do with the political state of Islam in those times, as the Arabs of the time would never accept anyone as their leader or Ameer other than from the family of the Quraish. [SOURCE](http://islamhelpline.net/answer/714/only-quraish-can-be-khalifas)

Comment: @Shahab I wonder if this is an agreed upon explanation as there are many ahadith warning the Ummah from being reigned by the Turks.

Comment: @Medi1Saif If you see the source cited above, it says that 
the scholars of the major schools of thought in Islam are unanimous in their opinion regarding this.

Comment: @Shahab: how do we verify is majority of hardly few agree on this opnion? do you blindly believe on this website?

Comment: @Farhan good point. Maybe there is something to do with language of Quraish?

Comment: @Shahab actually the majority says that being from among Quraish is a major quality of the Muslim ruler. The only people saying otherwise I know of is the Ibadi sect.

Comment: @Medi1Saif can you explain why the hadith warn about turks?